# Mock Prisma Client in Node.js

Tags: node.js, prisma

I need to mock my postgres, ORM I'm using is prisma. And I want to mock that So I can pass dummy data and use that Controller as an API controller. while using prisma-mock package, it's documentation shows to use prisma mock with jest. Similar like `Sequelize-Mock`. But Unfortuantely Cannot

Comment: have you try this https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing

Comment: Yupp, I did But no luck

Comment: show code here what you did and where you are facing issue. then may be someone will help